# Error while inserting values from table to table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert rows as result of a query to an other table.

I am getting this error:

> The subquery return multiple values. This is not allowed when the subquery follows =,! =, <, <=,>,> = Or when it is used as an expression.

Although, when I only select one line (TOP 1) of the select statement it works fine.

The whole query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO ABSENCES (MATRICULE, ID_ABSENCE, CODE_COMPTEUR, DT_ABSENCE, DT_REPRISE_TRAVAIL, NBJ_OUVRE,ROW_ID)
SELECT 
   dv.MATRICULE, 
   dv.ID_DEMANDE, 
   dv.CODE_PROCESSUS, 
   dg.DT_DEPART, 
   dg.DT_RETOUR, 
   dg.DUREE, 
   dv.DT_DEMANDE
FROM DMD_DIVERS dv
INNER JOIN DMD_CONGE dg 
   ON dv.ID_DEMANDE=dg.ID_DEMANDE
WHERE 
   dv.CODE_PROCESSUS = 'P_CNG_AM' 
   AND dv.ETAT = 'N' 
   AND dv.DECISION = 'I'
   AND dv.MATRICULE = 228900
ORDER BY dg.DT_DEPART DESC
```

Comment: Your code has no subqueries so it cannot return this error -- unless one of the "tables" is a view.

Comment: Just a guess, but does the table you're inserting into have a trigger?

Comment: Exactly there was a trigger on ABSENCES table. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Table ABSENCES has a unique constraint ( probable ID_ABSENCES )
The result from the SELECT statement contains multiple instances of the same ID